# Cannot destructure property 'chat' of '_ref' as it is undefined (firebase & react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code that runs to fetch data from a firebase collection:

```
useEffect(() => {
db.collection("chatLists")
.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
  if(snapshot) {
    let chattingLists = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      if(doc.data().users.includes(user.email)) {
        return {
          chat: doc.data(),
          id: doc.id
        };
      }
    })
    if(chattingLists !== [undefined]) {
      setChatLists(chattingLists ? chattingLists : []);
    }
  }
})}, []);
```

Basically I am fetching all the docs of collection 'chatLists' and seeing if an array called "users" which has two users includes the current users name who's using the app, if they do, I return them all and all the filtered docs get inputed inside the chattingLists variable. Then I set it to a useState and then I try to map all of them:

```
return (
<div>
  <button onClick={addChat}>
    Add a chat
  </button>
  <>
    {chatLists !== undefined && chatLists.map(({chat, id}) => (
      <p>{id}</p> {/*Anything that i try to get from the chat or id doesn't work and i get error message*/}
    ))}
  </>
</div>
```

)

However, I get the error: "Cannot destructure property 'chat' of '_ref' as it is undefined."

And the weird part is that in some chrome users it works perfectly how I want it to and no errors but in some others I get that error message above.

Also, each doc in the chatLists looks like this:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [`array-contains`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) query operator instead of fetching all documents from the collection and manually filtering the documents. This will save you plenty of read charges.
2. You must return a value from the function in `map` but currently you return nothing when the document does not contain given email and hence there are undefined items in that array.

Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
useEffect(() => {
  db.collection("chatLists")
    .where("users", "array-contains", "user.email")
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const chats = querySnapshot.docs.map((d) => ({
        id: d.id,
        chat: d.data(),
      }));
      setChatLists(chats);
    });
}, []);
```